# 2D basic transformation combination

Tags: c++, opengl, 2d, glut, affinetransform

I have a 2D transformation problem in OpenGL. My program draws two letters on screen and, by pressing assigned keys, letters have to move up (GLUT_KEY_UP) down (GLUT_KEY_DOWN) left (GLUT_KEY_LEFT) right (GLUT_KEY_RIGHT) and rotate CW (GLUT_KEY_HOME) and CCW (GLUT_KEY_END). (On keys GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP and GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN both letters rotate around their own centers simultaniously in oposite directions, pressing e.g. GLUT_KEY_UP after GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP moves both letters in a correct direction).

I can't make the letters do the correct movement (up, down, left or right) after the objects had been rotated with GLUT_KEY_HOME or GLUT_KEY_END:

```cpp
case GLUT_KEY_HOME: //rotate clockwise around the center of the model
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    setRotationMatrix(-angle, modelSizeX, modelSizeY);
    glMultMatrixf(rotationMatrix);  // multiply current Modelview Matrix by rotate-and-translate matrix
    display();
    break;
```

Function that 'sets' the rotation matrix inserts angle and rotation point into Identity matrix [4x4]:

```cpp
void setRotationMatrix(float theta, float x0, float y0)
{
    theta = theta * (2 * acos(0.0)) / 180; // convert theta from degrees to radian
    rotationMatrix[0] = cos(theta);
    rotationMatrix[1] = sin(theta);
    rotationMatrix[4] = -sin(theta);
    rotationMatrix[5] = cos(theta);
    rotationMatrix[12] = ((x0 * 0.5f) * (1 - cos(theta)) + (y0 * 0.5f) * sin(theta));
    rotationMatrix[13] = ((y0 * 0.5f) * (1 - cos(theta)) - (x0 * 0.5f) * sin(theta));
}
```

After the objects have been rotated, if I press KEY_UP, they move not 'up' (in normal direction against x axis ) but in the direction normal to the horizontal plane of the object after rotation (slightly sideways).

```cpp
case GLUT_KEY_UP:
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glTranslated(0, delta, 0);
    display();
    break;
```

how do I make it move straightly to the 'north', meaning, not the 'north' of the object but the 'north' of my coordinate system?

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL/glut.h> 
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

#define EscKey 27
#define PlusKey 43
#define MinusKey 45

struct Point
{
    int x, y;
};

double pi = 2 * acos(0.0);
void reshape(int w, int h);
void display();
void drawInitials();
void processNormalKeys(unsigned char key, int x, int y);
void processSpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y);
void setRotationMatrix(float theta, float x0, float y0);
void readFromFile();
void lineto(Point p);
void moveto(Point p);
void drawM();
void drawJ();
vector <Point> point;
vector <int>   code;
Point currentPoint;
int modelSizeX = 202; int modelSizeY = 89;
int letterMSizeX = 107; int letterJSizeX = 78;
int   delta = 5;        // movement size
float zoomRate = 0.1;   // scale-and-translate rate: 0.1 = resize by 10%
float angle = 1, rotaterR = 1 * pi / 180, rotater,  angleCount = 0.0; // saved rotation angle
GLfloat modelviewStateMatrix[16];


int windowSizeX, windowSizeY;


boolean separate = false;

float rotationMatrix[16] = { 1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
                             0.0f, 1.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
                             0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
                             0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,  1.0f };

float plusKeyMatrix[16] = { 1.0f + zoomRate, 0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
                             0.0f, 1.0f + zoomRate,  0.0f,  0.0f,
                             0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
                           -(modelSizeX * zoomRate * 0.5f), -(modelSizeY * zoomRate * 0.5f),  0.0f,  1.0f };

float minusKeyMatrix[16] = { 1.0f - zoomRate, 0.0f,  0.0f,  0.0f,
                             0.0f, 1.0f - zoomRate,  0.0f,  0.0f,
                             0.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f,  0.0f,
                             modelSizeX * zoomRate * 0.5f,    modelSizeY * zoomRate * 0.5f,  0.0f,  1.0f };

void readFromFile()
{
    fstream f("initials_points_2.txt", ios::in);
    int pointNumber;
    Point p;
    f >> pointNumber;
    for (int i = 0; i < pointNumber;i++)
    {
        f >> p.x >> p.y;
        point.push_back(p);
    }
    int movesNumber, m;
    f >> movesNumber;
    for (int i = 0; i < movesNumber; i++)
    {
        f >> m; code.push_back(m);
    }
    f.close();
}
void moveto(Point p)
{
    currentPoint.x = p.x; currentPoint.y = p.y;
}
void lineto(Point p)
{
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2i(currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
    glVertex2i(p.x, p.y);
    glEnd();
    currentPoint.x = p.x; currentPoint.y = p.y;
}

void setRotationMatrix(float theta, float x0, float y0)
{
    theta = theta * (2 * acos(0.0)) / 180; // convert theta from degrees to radian
    rotationMatrix[0] = cos(theta);
    rotationMatrix[1] = sin(theta);
    rotationMatrix[4] = -sin(theta);
    rotationMatrix[5] = cos(theta);
    rotationMatrix[12] = ((x0 * 0.5f) * (1 - cos(theta)) + (y0 * 0.5f) * sin(theta));
    rotationMatrix[13] = ((y0 * 0.5f) * (1 - cos(theta)) - (x0 * 0.5f) * sin(theta));
}

void drawM()
{
    int i = 1;
    moveto(point[0]);
    while (code[i] > 0 && i < code.size())
    {
        lineto(point[code[i] - 1]);
        i++;
    }

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(letterMSizeX, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(letterMSizeX, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(letterMSizeX, modelSizeY, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(letterMSizeX, modelSizeY, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, modelSizeY, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, modelSizeY, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2i(0, 0); glVertex2i(letterMSizeX, modelSizeY);
    glVertex2i(letterMSizeX, 0); glVertex2i(0, modelSizeY);
    glEnd();
}
void drawJ()
{
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    int i = 14;
    moveto(point[-1 * (code[i]) - 1]);
    i++;
    while (i < code.size())
    {
        lineto(point[code[i] - 1]);
        i++;
    }

    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex3f((modelSizeX - letterJSizeX), 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f((modelSizeX - letterJSizeX), modelSizeY, 0.0);
    glVertex3f((modelSizeX - letterJSizeX), modelSizeY, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(modelSizeX, modelSizeY, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(modelSizeX, modelSizeY, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(modelSizeX, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(modelSizeX, 0.0, 0.0);
    glVertex3f((modelSizeX - letterJSizeX), 0.0, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2i(letterMSizeX + 17, 0); glVertex2i(modelSizeX, modelSizeY);
    glVertex2i(letterMSizeX + 17, modelSizeY); glVertex2i(modelSizeX, 0);
    glEnd();


}

void drawInitials()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    setRotationMatrix(-rotater, letterMSizeX, modelSizeY);
    glMultMatrixf(rotationMatrix);  // multiply current Modelview Matrix by rotate-and-translate matrix
    drawM();
    glTranslatef(-letterMSizeX * 0.5, -modelSizeY * 0.5, 0);
    glPopMatrix();

    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef((modelSizeX - letterJSizeX), 0, 0);
    setRotationMatrix(rotater, letterJSizeX, modelSizeY);
    glMultMatrixf(rotationMatrix);  // multiply current Modelview Matrix by rotate-and-translate matrix
    glTranslatef(-(modelSizeX - letterJSizeX), 0, 0);
    drawJ();
    glPopMatrix();
}

void processNormalKeys(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{
    switch (key)
    {
    case EscKey:
        exit(0);
        break;
    case PlusKey:                      // "zoom in" 
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glMultMatrixf(plusKeyMatrix);  // multiply current Modelview Matrix by scale-and-translate matrix   
        display();
        break;
    case MinusKey:                     // "zoom out"    
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glMultMatrixf(minusKeyMatrix); // multiply current Modelview Matrix by scale-and-translate matrix
        display();
        break;
    }
}

void processSpecialKeys(int key, int x, int y) {
    switch (key) {
    case GLUT_KEY_UP:
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glTranslated(0, delta, 0);
        display();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_DOWN:
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glTranslated(0, -delta, 0);
        display();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_LEFT:
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glTranslated(-delta, 0, 0);
        display();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_RIGHT:
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glTranslated(delta, 0, 0);
        display();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_HOME: //rotate clockwise around the center of the model
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        setRotationMatrix(-angle, modelSizeX, modelSizeY);
        glMultMatrixf(rotationMatrix);  // multiply current Modelview Matrix by rotate-and-translate matrix
        display();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_END: //rotate counterclockwise around the center of the model
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        setRotationMatrix(angle, modelSizeX, modelSizeY);
        glMultMatrixf(rotationMatrix);  // multiply current Modelview Matrix by rotate-and-translate matrix
        display();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP:
        rotater -= rotaterR;
        if (rotater <= -2 * pi)
            rotater += 2 * pi;
        display();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN:
        rotater += rotaterR;
        if (rotater >= 2 * pi)
            rotater -= 2 * pi;
        display();
        break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    currentPoint.x = 0; currentPoint.y = 0;
    readFromFile();

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 150);
    glutCreateWindow("OpenGL lab");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);

    glutKeyboardFunc(processNormalKeys);
    glutSpecialFunc(processSpecialKeys);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    windowSizeX = w;
    windowSizeY = h;
    gluOrtho2D(-modelSizeX, modelSizeX * 2, -modelSizeY, modelSizeY * 2); // World size
}
void display()
{
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    glLoadIdentity();
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    glVertex2i(-windowSizeX, 0); glVertex2i(windowSizeX, 0);
    glVertex2i(0, -windowSizeY); glVertex2i(0, windowSizeY);
    glEnd();
    glPopMatrix();

    glColor3d(1, 0, 0);
    drawInitials();

    glPointSize(5);
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex3f(modelSizeX * 0.5, modelSizeY * 0.5, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(letterMSizeX * 0.5, modelSizeY * 0.5, 0.0);
    glVertex3f(letterJSizeX * 0.5 + letterMSizeX + 17, modelSizeY * 0.5, 0.0);
    glEnd();

    glFlush();
}
```

vertices file: [initials_points_2.txt](https://github.com/vespertinetale/LR3/blob/df2af8755a80c473d2b6dd0e2bf560388d6a2696/initials_points_2.txt)

I was trying to:

- encapsulate _HOME/_END rotation with glPushMatrix()/glPopMatrix()
- revert the rotation after the drawal of the object by multiplying MODELVIEW matrix with (-angle, same point)
- was trying to drop glMultMatrix() and use glTranslate(), glRotate()

none of them had worked as I intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what I was doing wrong: buttons GLUT_KEY_HOME/GLUT_KEY_END should be performing rotations similar to those of GLUT_KEY_PAGE_UP/GLUT_KEY_PAGE_DOWN:

- increase current rotation **angle** for the whole model (new variable to save rotation angle around the middle of the model);
- call display method();

Then, inside display() method:

- push current matrix into stack;
- rotate model by the **angle**;
- another push matrix into stack
- rotate letters by the rotater variable changed in PAGE_UP/PAGE_DOWN
  draw letters
- pop matrix
- pop matrix;

Code on keys:

```cpp
   case GLUT_KEY_HOME: //rotate clockwise around the center of the model
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        angle -= rotationRate;
        if (angle <= -2 * pi)
            angle += 2 * pi;
        display();
        break;
    case GLUT_KEY_END: //rotate counterclockwise around the center of the model
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        angle += rotationRate;
        if (angle >= 2 * pi)
            angle -= 2 * pi;
        display();
        break;
```

edited drawInitials() method (called from display() method):

```cpp
void drawInitials()
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glPushMatrix();
    setRotationMatrix(angle, modelSizeX, modelSizeY); //set rotation matrix to rotate around the center of the model by current angle
    glMultMatrixf(rotationMatrix);  // multiply current Modelview Matrix by rotate-and-translate matrix
        glPushMatrix();
        setRotationMatrix(-rotater, letterMSizeX, modelSizeY); //set to rotate around the center of the letter M by current rotater Clockwise
        glMultMatrixf(rotationMatrix);  // multiply current Modelview Matrix by rotate-and-translate matrix
        drawM();
        glPopMatrix();

        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef((modelSizeX - letterJSizeX), 0, 0);  // move OX axis by the size of letter M + space between the letters 
        setRotationMatrix(rotater, letterJSizeX, modelSizeY);//set to rotate around the center of the letter J by current rotater Counter Clockwise
        glMultMatrixf(rotationMatrix);  // multiply current Modelview Matrix by rotate-and-translate matrix
        glTranslatef(-(modelSizeX - letterJSizeX), 0, 0); // return OX axis to its previous place
        drawJ();
        glPopMatrix();
    glPopMatrix();
}
```

In setRotationMatrix() remove conversion into radian;

Add new variable rotationRate to use it as an incriment for both rotations:

```cpp
float angle; 
// saved rotation angle around center of the model (radian) 
float rotater;
// rotater - saved rotation angle around center of the letter (radian)
float rotationRate = 1 * pi / 180;  // rotation rate (radian), ex rotaterR
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following steps:

- At first, rotate the object on the object coordinate system.
- Next, place the object into the space (coordinate system) that you are considering the directions {up, down, left, and right} in.

i.e. for first rotation, the center must be the value in the object coordinate system. For example, object coordinate system is often defined as the origin equals to the center of object. In this case, rotation center is (0,0,0).

```
glPushMatrix();
//2nd step : Place the object
glTranslatef( ... );
//1st step : rotate the object
glRotatef( ... );
//object draw code
//(all vertex value is in the object coordinate system)
glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it served as a good reference point!